# Facebook video embedding status is enabled but it doesn't display

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I added open graph tags to the following URL to enable video embedding on Facebook: http://store.staging.shoppost.in/Sm0OAdAleEW--6J6AW8brw

This worked up until a few days ago but now the thumbnail on the Facebook post no longer has the play button. Clicking on it now redirects to the URL rather than displaying the embedded Flash video. The puzzling thing is that the Facebook Object Debugger says there are no errors and that video embedding is enabled (as seen [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://store.staging.shoppost.in/Sm0OAdAleEW--6J6AW8brw)).

Here are the open graph tags I am using:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Wow, Look at that!" />
<meta property="og:type" content="product.item" />
<meta property="og:description" content="and now something that  you&amp;#39;ve never seen  before in all your days...." />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://media.staging.shoppost.in/physicalitems/0e1a8af7-736f-443e-b5e5-d09830c88f38/art/38213a2d-fe0e-4898-9d0e-80305c6e7230.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Shoppost" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://store.staging.shoppost.in/ps/Sm0OAdAleEW--6J6AW8brw" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://store.staging.shoppost.in/ps/Sm0OAdAleEW--6J6AW8brw"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://store.staging.shoppost.in/Sm0OAdAleEW--6J6AW8brw" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_us"/>
<meta property="og:video:height" content="296" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="526" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash"/>
```

I have been struggling with this for a while, please let me know if you have any insight. Thanks!